# disable cross domain database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, whm

hopefully this is the right place to ask as Google is giving me results to the opposite of my problem.

So, i have two domains are under a whm account, and the issue is this:

wordpress has been installed on dev.domain1.com, and after transferring the files of this dev site to domain2.com, i discovered it's displaying dev.domain1.com's content (and is also reading from dev.domain1.com's wordpress database), and domain2.com/wp-admin redirects to dev.domain1.com/wp-admin as well.

Is there anyway to disable this from happening? Across all domains under said whm account?

Thanks

Comment: please correct stuff by editing your question instead of using comments. From feeling your search term and title is totally wrong, there is no "cross domain" problem here. You just need to get out how to deploy a wordpress installation from one server to the other like here https://www.itworld.com/article/2946238/development/from-dev-to-production-the-proper-way-to-take-a-wordpress-site-live.html ...correct?

Comment: appreciate your reply. post has been edited and commented deleted. 

I appreciate the article you sent over, the concern is that domain2.com can read domain1.com's wp database, which ideally shouldn't be the case. It should show a database connection error instead?

Comment: it is ok that the sites can connect to the others database if you like it that way. the question is more like why does it connect to the other Db. You'll need to figure out all connection strings after copying the site and correct them as described in at the bottom of the article.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following options in the options table in database :-

Wordpress Address

Site Address

Please refer to below link for more details/steps

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-update-urls-when-moving-your-wordpress-site/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is domain2.com can access the wordpress database on domain1.com. 

To clarify, these are two different domains, and there are no databases on domain2.com. 

Ideally, I'd like for this interaction to be prevented, and show a database connection error instead.

Comment: @xa3d You can change the database configuration in the file wp-config.php. Right now the database configuration must be pointing to database used by domain1. Change this to anything you like.